# How to get to a chest located under the bottom of the ocean in Godus?

Tags: android, godus

In the Android version of Godus I got a chest that seems to be under the very lowest level. How can I get to it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the lowest level at the moment, but there are in fact lower levels that you unlock later on. After unlocking those levels you can sculpt away the land to get the chest.

Comment: I didn't see any card that unlocks farther levels. I already have the sculpt the oceans card. What card allows it, and what is needed to get it?

Comment: You might need to unlock another zone to reach the lowest portion. See how its faded white at the bottom of the image? You haven't unlocked that area yet. In that area there should be deeper layers.